# php file_get_contents pulling text different to source code

Tags: php

I am trying to get information from a websites with daily exchange rates. 
the text show fine on the output but the rates are not showing 
even though they show on the source code.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

Comment: they might be xhr requests, check browser's console

Comment: The exchange rates could be encoded or hidden in js. Where is th epage source ? and what comes back ?

Comment: it s from ...<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://www.exchange-rates.org/GetCustomContent.aspx?sid=RT000DMR2&amp;type=RatesTable&amp;stk=0ME6AZQ352" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<div>Source: <a href="http://www.exchange-rates.org/">www.exchange-rates.org</a></div>